# Add rows to the datatable-Error loading dependencies

Tags: plotly-dash

I want to create an app that a user can upload CSV files and it will show a data table that the user can edit, add columns and add rows. There are also two dropdowns that contain the value of the columns of the data table. But I get Error loading dependencies after I run the code. Can anyone teach me how to fix this error?

Below is the code:

```
import base64
import io
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='datatable-upload',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%', 'height': '60px', 'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px', 'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px', 'textAlign': 'center', 'margin': '10px'
        },
    ),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Input(
            id='adding-rows-name',
            placeholder='Enter a column name...',
            value='',
            style={'padding': 10}
        ),
        html.Button('Add Column', id='adding-rows-button', n_clicks=0)
    ], style={'height': 50}),

    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
    html.Button('Add Row', id='editing-rows-button', n_clicks=0),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='data_selector1',
        options=[       
            {'label': '', 'value': ''}
        ],
         value=[]
    ),
   dcc.Dropdown(
        id='data_selector2',
        options=[       
            {'label': '', 'value': ''}
        ],         
         value=[]
    ),
])


def parse_contents(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    if 'csv' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
        return pd.read_csv(
            io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
    elif 'xls' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
        return pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))


@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              [Input('datatable-upload', 'contents')],
              [State('datatable-upload', 'filename')])
def update_output(contents, filename):
    if contents is None:
        return []
    df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
    return html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id='table',
            style_data={
                     'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                     'height': 'auto'
                     },
             style_table={'overflowX': 'scroll',
                          'maxHeight': '300',
                          'overflowY': 'scroll'},
             style_cell={                     
                     'minWidth': '150px', 'maxWidth': '180px',
                     'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                     'textAlign': 'left'
                },
            style_header={                   
                    'fontWeight': 'bold',                   
                                    },            
            fixed_rows={ 'headers': True, 'data': 0 },           
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, 'deletable': True, 'renamable': True} for i in df.columns],
            data=df.to_dict("records"),                             
            row_deletable=True,
            filter_action="native",
            sort_action="native",
            sort_mode='multi',
            editable=True,
        )
    ])

#The code will work if I remove this function     
@app.callback(                   
    Output('table', 'data'),
    [Input('editing-rows-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('table', 'data'),
     State('table', 'columns')])
def add_row(n_clicks, rows, columns):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        rows.append({i['id']: '' for i in columns})
    return rows

@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'columns'),
    [Input('adding-rows-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('adding-rows-name', 'value'),
     State('table', 'columns')])
def update_columns(n_clicks, value, existing_columns):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        existing_columns.append({
            'id': value, 'name': value,
            'renamable': True, 'deletable': True
        })
    return existing_columns

@app.callback(Output('data_selector1', 'options'),
              [Input('table', 'data')])
def update_dropdown(rows):
    if rows is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    print('updating menus')
    columns = df.columns
    col_labels = [{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in columns]
    return col_labels

@app.callback(Output('data_selector2', 'options'),
              [Input('table', 'data')])
def update_dropdown2(rows):
    if rows is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    print('updating menus')
    columns = df.columns
    col_labels = [{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in columns]
    return col_labels


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

The code will work if I remove the add rows to the data table function.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @alexherm the webpage shows Error loading dependencies after I run the code.